# How to read barcodes in python?

Tags: python, barcode-scanner

For a school assignment I'm making a "smartfridge", To register the products in the fridge i am using the MCR12-USB barcodescanner: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1203.
Connected to a raspberry pi model B3+

I want to get the barcode into a variable to lookup with the UPC api.
Any way to get the barcode is good.

I've tried to get the barcode with an input field (barcode setup as keyboard; hidraw0).
But the problem with tis approach is that the cursor isn't automatically in the inputfield.

Now I'm trying to get the barcode from the reader via the serial interface (barcode setup as RS232) but i can't get it to work properly, I don't really know which port to open, i've tried serial0, serial1, ttyAMA0 and ttyS0 but on all of them I just get a blank line.

```
import requests
import serial

def barcode():
    with serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=1) as port:
        while True:

            print(port.name)
            line = port.readline()
            print(line)
            url = "https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/%s/%s" % (line, api_key)

            headers = {
                'cache-control': "no-cache",
            }

            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

            print("-----" * 5)
            print(line)
            print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
            print("-----" * 5 + "\n")
```

I expect the output to be the barcode but I only get a blank line

Comment: What happens when you do an explicit REST GET to your url?

Comment: I get a json response

Comment: Try printing `url` also before the GET call. and after the GET call, just print `response` Also, do you see any exceptions?

Comment: The product doc says that the device provides the barcode as keyboard input: `When a barcode is scanned, the raw data is decoded, parity-checked and spit out as if they were typed on a keyboard.` Have you tried NOT using serial and reading the barcode in the same way you read keyboard input? Just a shot in the dark, but usually the answers are hiding in the documentation.

Comment: @BrandonTweed when i do this i get the error: serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (22, 'Invalid argument')

Comment: @susenj the url is: https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/b''/AC939DFDCBCA58BD57DF47EF508DE3B8
and the response is: <Response [400]>
-------------------------
b''
{
  "error": true,
  "message": "Bad Request. The code you are trying to enter does not contain all digits.",
  "status": 400
}
-------------------------

Comment: if you're using the USB cable supplied with your barcode reader you should use `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Have you tried that one? you can do: `ls /dev/tty*` to make sure it's there. Otherwise please explain how you are wiring the reader to the RPi

Comment: @MarcosG. The barcode scanner is indeed connected to the pi with the provided USB cable, the problem is, ttyUSB0 isn't there... Do you have any idea how I can get it to show-up?

Comment: try `lsusb`, you should see something like the chip vendor, according to the manual you need a driver to use the serial interface.

Comment: By the way: have you scanned the codes in the manual to enter the setup and change the device to serial? I think you have to scan the codes on top of page 3 first and then the one in the middle of page 12, right?

Comment: Yes, I did, I haven't installed a driver tough but I thought I didn't need a driver for the rs232 interface. lsusb shows Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0483:0011 STMicroelectronics ; could it be this?

Comment: What I understand from the manual is that you have to setup the USB as virtual serial port and then you have the choice to use another separate RS232 interface. But to use that one you have to wire it to your Pi, it seems easier to go with the USB. The STMicroelectronics is not it, what else you have?

Comment: These are the other ones:
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: I don't think it's any of those, try `dmesg | grep usb` right after connecting the USB to see if you get more details

Comment: I don't really know what to make up from all of the things it says:
https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0qiFzGgl3dKUzmGPoEiNxAB1A#Screenshot_2019-06-11_at_20.10

Comment: It's OK with the screenshot, it seems it's still a keyboard for your computer, I think you should try again scanning the config codes and change it to virtual COM. Then you should see the `/dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: Maybe you can try to [monitor the device as keyboard](https://superuser.com/a/834336) to see the keystrokes are correct according to the manual?

Comment: Now i have ttyACM0, but that's the same right?

Comment: I think that's the serial UART on you Rpi, so no, it's not the USB device

Comment: When i try on ttyACM0 i get the error 'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

Comment: Yeah,  makes sense, you have nothing connected to the UART pins on your Pi, hence you're receiving nothing, let me write you a more detailed answer for you to change the mode to USB virtual.

Comment: Thanks a lot already! appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is seen by the Rpi as a keyboard by default. If you want to use the USB as a serial port you have to change the configuration.

Follow these steps:

-On a new terminal write: `xinput list` and find the ID of the barcode reader (a number, id=3 or 10, you should find it by name)

-Then write: `xinput test xx` where xx is the number you got on the previous step

-Now scan the barcode on top of page <kbd>3</kbd> of the manual, until you see `02501` coming on the terminal

-Next scan barcode in the middle of page <kbd>12</kbd>, until you see `000603` coming out on the terminal

Now disconnect and reconnect your reader and you should see `/dev/ttyUSB0` when you do a `ls /dev/tty*`. This means your device is ready to be used as a virtual serial port and your code should work now.

Comment: When I type xinput list it returns "unable to connect to X server

Comment: type `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Comment: Still returns the same

Comment: what Linux are you on?

Comment: The latest version of raspbian

Comment: But you don't have X windows... do you have another Linux computer to try this out?

Comment: I rebooted my raspberry pi and it works perfectly fine now! thanks for the help!